# Query by computed property in python mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoengine

I wondered if it is possible to query documents in MongoDB by computed properties using mongoengine in python.

Currently, my model looks like this:

```py
class SnapshotIndicatorKeyValue(db.Document):
    meta = {"collection": "snapshot_indicator_key_values"}

    snapshot_id = db.ObjectIdField(nullable=False)
    indicator_key_id = db.ObjectIdField(nullable=False)
    value = db.FloatField(nullable=False)
    created_at = db.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = db.DateTimeField()

    @property
    def snapshot(self):
        return Snapshot.objects(id=self.snapshot_id).first()

    def indicator_key(self):
        return IndicatorKey.objects(id=self.indicator_key_id).first()
```

When I do for example `SnapshotIndicatorKeyValue .objects().first().snapshot`, I can access the `snapshot`property.

But when I try to query it, it doesn't work. For example:

```py
SnapshotIndicatorKeyValue.objects(snapshot__date_time__lte=current_date_time)
```

I get the error `mongoengine.errors.InvalidQueryError: Cannot resolve field "snapshot"``

Is there any way to get this working with queries?
I need to query `SnapshotIndicatorKeyValue` based on a property of `snapshot`.

Comment: MongoEngine main contributor here, no this is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to query the `snapshot` property directly through mongoengine, you can reference the related `snapshot` object rather than the `snapshot_id` in your `SnapshotIndicatorKeyValue` document definition.

An amended model using a [Reference field](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#reference-fields) would be like this:

```
from mongoengine import Document, ReferenceField

class Snapshot(Document)
property_abc = RelevantPropertyHere() # anything you need

class SnapshotIndicatorKeyValue(Document):
snapshot = ReferenceField(Snapshot)
```

You would sucessively save an instance of `Snapshot` and an instance of `SnapshotIndicatorKeyValue` like this:

```
sample_snapshot = Snapshot(property_abc=relevant_value_here) # anything you need
sample_snapshot.save()

sample_indicatorkeyvalue = SnapshotIndicatorKeyValue()
sample_indicatorkeyvalue.snapshot = sample_snapshot
sample_indicatorkeyvalue.save()
```

You can then refer to any of the `snapshot`'s properties through:

```
SnapshotIndicatorKeyValue.objects.first().snapshot.property_abc
```